# Does karma have effects, only if they are done physically? Or also mentally?

Tags: theravada, karma

I know Theravada Buddhism has 5 precepts:

- killing other beings
- stealing, or taking by force what is not given
- no sexual relations other than your married soulmate
- lying and incorrect speech
- consuming intoxicating substances

These are physical actions and give bad karma.

What if I have negative thoughts in my mind? Would it have the same repercussions as physical actions, or would it be less severe?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Please see the questions linked to this question. They already have answers to your question.

Comment: negative thoughts cause suffering & hindrances to your mind but, yes, their repercussions are incomparably less severe. For example, if you commit adultery, you could lose your job, your wife (or husband), family, your wealth. If you kill, you end up in prison.

Comment: thank you for clarification